# ant build (javac) gives "cannot find symbol" error even though the needed javax.jms class is loaded

Tags: java, ant

I am using my company's Ant scripts to compile a class that uses the javax.jms API. It can't seem to find any of this API's classes' method's even though the ant script shows it is loading the class (and I did confirm that the jms.jar is in the classpath the Ant build is using). I am also using Eclipse and this class compiles fine in Eclipse (using the same jms.jar as is in the Ant Build script's classpath). I have looked at the javax.jms API and it looks to me like I am coding this correctly. Included below is an exceprt of the code followed by an excerpt from the compile output.

**CODE EXCERPT**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;

Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:C:\\MQ-JNDI");
final InitialDirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext( environment );
final ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("PRIMARY_QCF");     
final Destination destination = (Destination)ctx.lookup("Q_LIST");
final javax.jms.Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
connection.start();
final Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage(msg);
producer.send(message);
```

**EXCERPT FROM ANT BUILD results**

```
[javac] [loading javax\naming\Context.class(javax\naming:Context.class)]
[javac] [loading javax\naming\directory\InitialDirContext.class(javax\naming\directory:InitialDirContext.class)]
[javac] [loading javax\jms\ConnectionFactory.class(javax\jms:ConnectionFactory.class)]
[javac] [loading javax\naming\Name.class(javax\naming:Name.class)]
[javac] [loading javax\jms\Destination.class(javax\jms:Destination.class)]
[javac] [loading javax\jms\Connection.class(javax\jms:Connection.class)]
[javac] C:\work\tla\ja11\projects\common\src\com\ntrs\tla\controller\MemberListController.java:1474: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method createConnection()
[javac] location: interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
[javac]         final javax.jms.Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
[javac]                                                        ^
[javac] [loading javax\jms\Session.class(javax\jms:Session.class)]
[javac] C:\work\tla\ja11\projects\common\src\com\ntrs\tla\controller\MemberListController.java:1479: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method createSession(boolean,int)
[javac] location: interface javax.jms.Connection
[javac]         final Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
[javac]                                           ^
[javac] [loading javax\jms\MessageProducer.class(javax\jms:MessageProducer.class)]
[javac] C:\work\tla\ja11\projects\common\src\com\ntrs\tla\controller\MemberListController.java:1483: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method createProducer(javax.jms.Destination)
[javac] location: interface javax.jms.Session
[javac]         final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
[javac]                                                 ^
[javac] [loading javax\jms\ObjectMessage.class(javax\jms:ObjectMessage.class)]
[javac] C:\work\tla\ja11\projects\common\src\com\ntrs\tla\controller\MemberListController.java:1486: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method send(javax.jms.ObjectMessage)
[javac] location: interface javax.jms.MessageProducer
[javac]         producer.send(message);
```

Comment: Couple of questions: Which version of JDK are you using, can you print out your exact classpath in the order the jars are being loaded (ant will print that for you with a debug flag) and can you list the import statements at the top of you source code?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out I had on old jms.jar file. Replaced it and it now compiles.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got an old version (1.0.x) of the JMS jar on your compiler classpath, either instead of or in front of the 1.1 version. The methods that the compiler is complaining about are ones that were introduced with JMS 1.1.

I would take a careful look at the classpath you're passing to the `<javac>` task to work out where the old JAR is coming from and exclude it.

Comment: Thanks so much - you were correct. Replaced with the proper JAR and it now compiles.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick mark to the left.